# Subtract parts of one frame from another frame (and match headers)

Tags: r

I'm trying to subtract one data frame (input2) from another (input1), but the columns are in a different order and the first column is a date string.

I thought I'd get away with something simple like output = input1 - input2, but obviously the non-numeric is an issue.  I'm also not sure if that would match the headers for me (I assume not).

Is there an easy way of doing this without looping through the frame?

```
input1 <- structure(list(X = c("Standard", "2020-03-24_1", "2020-03-23_2", 
"2020-03-20_3", "2020-03-19_4", "2020-03-18_5", "2020-03-17_6"
), Frank = c(228L, 582L, 129L, 419L, 255L, 574L, 424L), Ben = c(487L, 
540L, 162L, 366L, 292L, 283L, 211L), Millie = c(314L, 371L, 506L, 
143L, 448L, 381L, 369L), Simon = c(428L, 351L, 148L, 111L, 184L, 
225L, 276L), John = c(115L, 212L, 161L, 167L, 517L, 224L, 148L
)), row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = "data.frame")


input2 <- structure(list(X = c("Standard", "2020-03-24_1", "2020-03-23_2", 
"2020-03-20_3", "2020-03-19_4", "2020-03-18_5", "2020-03-17_6"
), Ben = c(315L, 297L, 284L, 347L, 581L, 231L, 365L), Frank = c(562L, 
556L, 174L, 296L, 172L, 359L, 125L), John = c(583L, 471L, 312L, 
258L, 450L, 142L, 478L), Millie = c(181L, 327L, 473L, 232L, 469L, 
443L, 462L), Simon = c(178L, 121L, 277L, 240L, 585L, 106L, 313L
)), row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could order the columns in one of the dataframe based on the names in second dataframe and subtract the values directly. Using `-1` since we want to ignore the first column.

```
input1[-1] - input2[names(input1)[-1]]

#  Frank  Ben Millie Simon John
#1  -334  172    133   250 -468
#2    26  243     44   230 -259
#3   -45 -122     33  -129 -151
#4   123   19    -89  -129  -91
#5    83 -289    -21  -401   67
#6   215   52    -62   119   82
#7   299 -154    -93   -37 -330
```

Comment: To keep the X column in the output, do I need to add it separetly?

Comment: @nicshah no, just assign the output as `input1[-1] <- input1[-1] - input2[names(input1)[-1]]`